# "it is currently in expansion" vs. "it is currently expanding"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, sentence

I would like to write the following sentence, but I am not sure which one should I use.

1. Football is one of the most popular sports worldwide and it is currently expanding.
2. Football is one of the most popular sports worldwide and it is currently in expansion.

Which sentence is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd write

> Football is one of the most popular sports worldwide and its popularity is  currently expanding.

Surely that's what you mean...the sport is not expanding. Its popularity is expanding. Or, simpler, growing. The sport is not really expanding/growing: the size of the field is the same; the number of players per side is not expanding...

For the difference between *expanding* and *expansion*, try a dictionary before asking a question directly about these two words.

Some people might want to place a comma before the *and* in my sentence; that is optional. It's optional because punctuation should only be used to *clarify*. Using a comma after *and* doesn't clarify anything, and the sentence reads quite well without it. Inlcuding one unnecessarily slows the reader.

Comment: "Some people" includes every major style guide and grammar, though you're free to include a reference justifying this particular idiosyncracy in punctuation.

Comment: The comma is certainly optional.